# HTML code retrieved using HttpGet does not return the full page

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup, http-get

When trying to pull all of the HTML code off of this website http://www.gasbuddy.com/GB_Price_List.aspx 
I run into the problem that only half of the page is put into my String.

I have tried several methods found all over SO, and other sources from Google searching, and none have worked to solve my issue.

This is my code that retrieves the page:

```
private class InternetGasBuddyConnection extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder(30000);
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        String result = "";
        try {
            HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
            InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String s = "";
            while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
                response.append(s);

            Log.d("before changing and parsing", response.toString());

            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(response.toString(), URL);

            result = response.toString();
            Log.d("no parsing", result.toString());

            result = doc.toString();        


            Log.d("after parsing", result);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("Darrell", result, e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(final String result) {
        Log.d("onPostExcecute()", result);
        htmlDoc = result;
    }
}
```

when I call the `Log.d("after parsing", result);` code, it displays this in my logcat:

```
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136): <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136): <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):  <head> 
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):   <title>USA and Canada Current Average Gas Prices By City/State/Province - GasBuddy.com</title> 
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):   <base id="ctl00_head_base" href="http://www.gasbuddy.com/" /> 
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):   <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/menu_v3.js?q=11"></script> 
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):   <link href="/Style.css" rel="Stylesheet" /> 
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):   <link href="/css/main.css?q=13" rel="Stylesheet" /> 
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):   <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" /> 
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" /> 
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):   <!--[if lt IE 7]>        <link href="/css/main_ie6.css?q=11" rel="Stylesheet" />        <![endif]--> 
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):   <!-- PUT THIS TAG IN THE head SECTION -->
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://partner.googleadservices.com/gampad/google_service.js"></script>
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):   <script type="text/javascript">  GS_googleAddAdSenseService("ca-pub-9634286501775085");  GS_googleEnableAllServices();</script>
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):   <script type="text/javascript">    var site;    var siteleft;    var siteright;    var site_length;    site="GasBuddy".toLowerCase();    site_length=site.length;    siteleft=site.substring(0,4);    siteright=site.substring(site_length-4,site_length);    site = siteleft + siteright;    GA_googleAddAttr("GasPri_URL", site);    </script>
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):   <script type="text/javascript">  GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-9634286501775085", "GasBuddy_Content_Top_728x90");  GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-9634286501775085", "GasBuddy_Content_Top_160x600");  GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-9634286501775085", "GasBuddy_Content_160x600_Bottom");</script>
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):   <script type="text/javascript">    GA_googleFetchAds();</script>
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):   <!-- END OF TAG FOR head SECTION -->
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):   <script type="text/javascript"> function getElementPosition(offsetTrail){    var offsetLeft = 0;    var offsetTop = 0;    while (offsetTrail){        offsetLeft += offsetTrail.offsetLeft;        offsetTop += offsetTrail.offsetTop;        offsetTrail = offsetTrail.offsetParent;    }    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mac') != -1 && typeof document.body.leftMargin != 'undefined'){        offsetLeft += document.body.leftMargin;        offsetTop += document.body.topMargin;    }    return {left:offsetLeft,top:offsetTop};}var ad_containers = [['divSkyscraper', 'divSky'], ['divLeaderboard','div728']];function moveAd() {  var i = 0;  for (i=0; i<ad_containers.length; i++){         if (document.getElementById(ad_containers[i][0])){         document.getElementById(ad_containers[i][0]).style.display = 'block';            document.getElementById(ad_containers[i][0]).style.position='absolute';            document.getElementById(ad_containers[i][0]).style.top=getElementPosition(document.getElementById(ad_containers[i][1])).top+"px";            document.getElementById(ad_containers[i][0]).style.left=getElementPosition(document.getElementById(ad_containers[i][1])).left+"px";         }    }        }    </script> 
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):   <script type="text/javascript">window._addWindowOnResize = function (func){if (typeof window.onresize == 'function'){var oldFunc = window.onresize;window.onresize = function() { oldFunc(); func(); }}else{window.onresize = func;}}</script> 
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):  </head> 
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):  <body> 
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):   <input id="adcoord" type="hidden" value="" /> 
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):   <input name="ctl00$serveradcoord" type="hidden" id="ctl00_serveradcoord" /> 
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):   <script type="text/javascript">        document.getElementById('adcoord').value= document.getElementById('ctl00_serveradcoord').value;    </script> 
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):   <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="GB_Price_List.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJODA2MjYxNTkwD2QWAmYPZBYEAgIPFgIeBGhyZWYFGGh0dHA6Ly93d3cuZ2FzYnVkZHkuY29tL2QCBQ9kFgRmDxYCHgRUZXh0BXk8aW5wdXQgaWQ9ImFkY29vcmQiIHR5cGU9ImhpZGRlbiIgdmFsdWU9ImxhdD00NC45NzIwODQ5MTYxMDUmYW1wO2xuZz0tOTMuMjU1Mzg2MzUyNTM5JmFtcDtydD1zY3JpcHQmYW1wO2NiPTQzMDA0MDc2OD4iIC8+ZAIJDxYCHwFlZGQFCm9rVVAnH00/+plv75hl5Bjosg==" />
07-23 13:19:57.833: D/after parsing(32136):    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAgLon7DQAgL9t/yMB9Wx1nzDGAm5Ha
```

As you can see, the line is not a html closing tag `</html>` why is it not all being placed within the String?

The rest of the HTML page is as follows (Well some of the rest, I've reached the body limit...):

```
</div> 

<div> 

<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAgK6gqnzAwL9t/yMBxUlbb+cRAiGT6aQPAFgtAU0IQZv" /> 
</div> 
<input id="adcoord" type="hidden" value="lat=44.972084916105&amp;lng=-93.255386352539&amp;rt=script&amp;cb=257130208>" /> 
<div id="main_wrapper" > 


<style type="text/css"> 
a.social { 
background-image: url(/images/art/social_small_sp.png); 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
padding: 3px 0px 3px 25px; 
margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px; 
text-decoration: underline; 
} 

a.social:hover { 
text-decoration: underline; 
} 

a.fb { background-position: 0px 2px;} 
a.tw { background-position: 0px -35px;} 

</style> 
<div style="font-size: 12px; height: 21px;"> 
<div style="float: left; padding-top: 3px;"> 
<a id="ctl00_GBTP_HyperLink1" href="Registration.aspx">[Become A Member]</a>&nbsp; 

<a id="ctl00_GBTP_HyperLink2" href="GB_Mem_log_in.aspx">[Log In]</a> 

</div> 
<div style="float: right; padding-top: 3px;"> 
<b>Follow Us</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/gasbuddy" target="_blank" class="social fb">Facebook</a> 

<a href="http://twitter.com/gasbuddy" target="_blank" class="social tw">Twitter</a> 

</div> 
</div> 


<style type="text/css"> 

td.gb_h_search { 
width: 240px; 
vertical-align: bottom; 
padding-bottom: 5px; 
font-size: 0px; 
} 

td.gb_h_search span { 
font-weight: bold; 
color: #555555; 
font-size: 17px; 
} 

td.gb_h_search div { 
margin-top: 2px; 
} 

td.gb_h_class { 
vertical-align: bottom; 
padding-bottom: 5px; 
} 

td.gb_h_class a { 
font-weight: bold; 
padding-left: 20px; 
} 

</style> 


<div id="header" onkeydown="return txtSearch_click(event);"> 
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 968px"> 
<tr> 
<td valign="top" width="425px" style=""> 
<a href="http://www.GasBuddy.com/"><img id="imgHeadbar" alt="" src="../images/logos/gasbuddy_logo.gif" width="425" height="58" /></a> 

</td> 
<td class="gb_h_search"> 

</td> 
<td class="gb_h_class"> 
<div> 

</div> 
</td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
</div> 



<style type="text/css"> 
#s_n_home a { 
background-image: url(/images/menu/tp_sp.png); 
background-position: 1px 1px; 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
vertical-align: bottom; 
padding-left: 24px; 
} 

#subnavi2 .s_n_feat { 
padding: 0 3px; 
} 

#s_n_home li.s_n_feat, #s_n_home li.s_n_feat:hover {background-position: 0px 0px;} 
#s_n_home a.s_n_feat_map {background-position: 4px 5px;} 
#s_n_home a.s_n_feat_tc {background-position: 4px -27px} 
#s_n_home a.s_n_feat_log {background-position: 3px -62px;} 
#s_n_home a.s_n_feat_chart {background-position: 4px -133px;} 
#s_n_home a.s_n_feat_prize {background-position: 4px -98px;} 
#s_n_home a.s_n_feat_tip {background-position: 3px -164px;} 
#s_n_home a.s_n_feat_blog {background-position: 3px -194px;} 
</style> 

<div id="navi2"> 
<ul> 
<li id="n_home"><a href="http://www.gasbuddy.com/">Home</a><span></span></li> 

<li id="n_blog"><a href="http://blog.gasbuddy.com/" target="_blank">Blog</a><span></span></li> 
<li id="n_gas" class="n_sel"><a href="/GB_Price_List.aspx">Gas Prices</a><span></span></li> 
<li id="n_charts"><a href="/gb_retail_price_chart.aspx?time=24">Price Charts</a><span></span></li> 
<li id="n_maps"><a href="/gb_gastemperaturemap.aspx">Gas Price Maps</a><span></span></li> 
<li id="n_points"><a href="/GB_Contest_Info.aspx?cntry=GB">Points &amp; Prizes</a><span></span></li> 
<li id="n_wireless"><a href="/GasBuddyMobileApps.aspx">Mobile Apps</a><span></span></li> 
<li id="n_media"><a href="http://media.gasbuddy.com/">Media</a><span></span></li> 

<li id="n_help"><a href="/gb_contact.aspx">Contact</a><span></span></li> 

<li id="n_advertise"><a href="/GB_AdvertiseWithUs.aspx">Advertise with us</a></li> 

</ul> 
</div> 

<div id="subnavi2"> 
<div id="s_n_home"> 
<ul> 
<li class="s_n_feat">Top Features:</li> 
<li><a href="/gb_gastemperaturemap.aspx" class="s_n_feat_map">Gas Price Heat Map</a><span></span></li> 
<li><a href="/Trip_Calculator.aspx" class="s_n_feat_tc">Trip Cost Calculator</a><span></span></li> 
<li><a href="/gb_retail_price_chart.aspx?time=24" class="s_n_feat_chart">Gas Price Charts</a><span></span></li> 
<li><a href="http://blog.gasbuddy.com/" target="_blank" class="s_n_feat_blog">GasBuddy Blog</a><span></span></li> 
<li><a href="GB_Contest_Info.aspx" class="s_n_feat_prize">Win Prizes</a><span></span></li> 
<li><a href="/GB_Fuel_Save.aspx" class="s_n_feat_tip">Fuel Saving Tips</a></li> 

</ul> 
</div> 

<div id="s_n_gas" class="s_n_on"> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="/Trip_Calculator.aspx">Trip Cost Calculator</a><span></span></li> 

<li><a href="/GB_StateList.aspx">Gas Prices by State/Province</a><span></span></li> 

<li><a href="/GB_Price_List.aspx">City &amp; State Averages</a><span></span></li> 

<li><a href="/GB_Fuel_Save.aspx">Fuel Saving Tips</a></li> 

</ul> 
</div> 

<div id="s_n_charts"> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="/gb_retail_price_chart.aspx?time=1">Past Month</a><span></span></li> 

<li><a href="/gb_retail_price_chart.aspx?time=12">Past Year</a><span></span></li> 

<li><a href="/gb_retail_price_chart.aspx?time=24">Past Two Years</a></li> 

</ul> 
</div> 

<div id="s_n_maps"> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="/GB_Map_Gas_Prices.aspx">Map Gas Prices</a><span></span></li> 

<li><a href="/gb_gastemperaturemap.aspx">Gas Price Heat Maps</a></li> 

</ul> 
</div> 

<div id="s_n_points"> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="/GB_Contest_Info.aspx?cntry=GB">Prize Give-away</a><span></span></li> 

<li><a href="/GB_Contest_Winners.aspx">Recent Winners</a><span></span></li> 

<li><a href="/GB_Choose_Site.aspx">Get Entries</a></li> 

</ul> 
</div> 

<div id="s_n_wireless"> 
<ul> 

<li><a href="/GasBuddyiPhoneApp.aspx">iPhone</a><span></span></li> 

<li><a href="/GasBuddyAndroidApp.aspx">Android</a><span></span></li> 

<li><a href="/GasBuddyWindowsPhoneApp.aspx">Windows Phone</a><span></span></li> 

<li><a href="/GasBuddyMobileApps.aspx#MobileWeb">Mobile Web</a><span></span></li> 

<li><a href="/GasBuddyBlackBerryApp.aspx">BlackBerry</a></li> 

</ul> 
</div> 

<div id="s_n_media"> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="http://media.gasbuddy.com/">Media Story Ideas</a></li> 

</ul> 
</div> 

<div id="s_n_help"> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="/gb_contact.aspx">Contact Us</a><span></span></li> 

<li><a href="http://media.gasbuddy.com/#ContactUs">Media Inquiries</a><span></span></li> 

<li><a href="/gb_aboutus.aspx">About Us</a></li> 

</ul> 
</div> 

<div id="s_n_blog"> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="http://blog.gasbuddy.com/" target="_blank">Recent Blog Posts</a></li> 

</ul> 
</div> 
<div id="s_n_advertise"> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="/GB_AdvertiseWithUs.aspx">Advertise with us</a></li> 

</ul> 
</div> 

<div id="s_n_fuel"> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="/Pricelock.aspx">Control your business' fuel costs</a><span></span></li> 

<li><a href="/PricelockHowItWorks.aspx">Get paid when fuel prices increase</a></li> 

</ul> 
</div> 
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var gb_m = new gb_Menu('navi2', 'subnavi2', 250, 15000, 'n_gas', false); 
</script> 


<div class="clearfix"> 
<div class="main_col"> 
<div class="main_boxGB"> 


<div id="div728"></div> 



<style type="text/css"> 
.listing { 
width: 100%; 
border: 1px solid #e2e2e2; 
} 

.listing td { 
font-size: 18px; 
color: #666; 
padding: 5px 5px; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2; 
} 

.listing a { 
color: #33528A; 
text-decoration: none; 
} 

.listing a:hover { 
text-decoration: underline; 
} 

.listing thead tr { 
background: #f2f2f2; 
} 

.listing tbody td:first-child { 
width: 500px; 
text-align: left; 
} 

.listing tbody tr:last-child td { 
border: 0; 
} 

.listing .p { 
text-align: right; 
padding: 0 30px 0 0; 
} 

.listing .up { 
color: #D5111B; 
} 

.listing .down { 
color: #339900; 
} 

.listing .gpd { 
padding-left: 30px; 
background: transparent url(/images/art/gpd_logo_sm.png) no-repeat 5px 50%; 
} 

.listing_nav { 
margin: 0 0 10px; 
padding: 0; 
overflow: hidden; 
width: 800px; 
} 

.listing_nav li { 
float: left; 
list-style: none none outside; 
width: 25%; 
} 

.listing_nav a { 
text-align: center; 
vertical-align: middle; 
padding: 20px 0; 
font-size: 18px; 
text-decoration: none; 
border: 1px solid #e2e2e2; 
border-right: 0; 
display: block; 

} 

.listing_nav a:hover { 
background: #f2f2f2; 
text-decoration: underline; 
} 

.listing_nav li:last-child a { 
border-right: 1px solid #e2e2e2; 
} 

</style> 


<ul class="listing_nav"> 
<li> 
<a href="/GB_Price_List.aspx?cntry=USA">US States</a> 

</li> 
<li> 
<a href="/GB_Price_List.aspx?cntry=USA#us_cities">US Cities</a> 

</li> 
<li> 
<a href="/GB_Price_List.aspx?cntry=CAN">Canadian Provinces</a> 


</li> 
<li> 
<a href="/GB_Price_List.aspx?cntry=CAN#can_cities">Canadian Cities</a> 

</li> 
</ul> 




<div id="ctl00_Content_GBFPL_pnlCanada"> 

<a name="can"></a> 
<div style="margin: 10px 0;"> 

<table class="listing" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
<td colspan="4"> 
Average Regular Gas Price By Canadian Province 
</td> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 

<tr> 
<td> 
<a href="http://www.Albertagasprices.com" target="_blank"> 

Alberta 
</a> 
</td> 
<td class="p"> 
117.6 
</td> 
<td class="p down"> 
-0.1 
</td> 
<td> 
<img src="/images/art/sm_trend_flat.gif" alt="" /> 

</td> 
</tr> 

<tr> 
<td> 
<a href="http://www.Manitobagasprices.com" target="_blank"> 

Manitoba 
</a> 
</td> 
<td class="p"> 
123.5 
</td> 
<td class="p down"> 
-0.4 
</td> 
<td> 
<img src="/images/art/sm_trend_down.gif" alt="" /> 

</td> 
</tr> 

<tr> 
<td> 
<a href="http://www.Saskgasprices.com" target="_blank"> 

Saskatchewan 
</a> 
</td> 
<td class="p"> 
126.3 
</td> 
<td class="p"> 
0.0 
</td> 
<td> 
<img src="/images/art/sm_trend_flat.gif" alt="" /> 

</td> 
</tr> 

<tr> 
<td> 
<a href="http://www.NewBrunswickgasprices.com" target="_blank"> 

New Brunswick 
</a> 
</td> 
<td class="p"> 
130.9 
</td> 
<td class="p down"> 
-0.1 
</td> 
<td> 
<img src="/images/art/sm_trend_flat.gif" alt="" /> 

</td> 
</tr> 

<tr> 
<td> 
<a href="http://www.Ontariogasprices.com" target="_blank"> 

Ontario 
</a> 
</td> 
<td class="p"> 
132.6 
</td> 
<td class="p up"> 
+0.3 
</td> 
<td> 
<img src="/images/art/sm_trend_flat.gif" alt="" /> 

</td> 
</tr> 

<tr> 
<td> 
<a href="http://www.PEIgasprices.com" target="_blank">
```

And so on... Only about one fifth of the full page is in the String...

Now, is there anyway to get all of the content from this page on GasBuddy into one String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set useragent

```
userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36")
```

Comment: httpGet.setHeader("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36");

Comment: tried it and I still get the same output... any other suggestions?

Comment: There is a max body size and connection timeout setting not sure where to set .Try setting them to bigger values.

Comment: I have already set the max String size using `StringBuilder` and have it set to 30000 characters. There are only 23000, I'll look into the timeOut option though, Thanks!

Comment: Still does the same thing... this is beginning to see hopeless lol

Comment: I'll mark yours as correct, after adding the methods and printing the number of lines added to the String I have found that the whole page IS being uploaded to the string. Having still not included the thing you suggested I will say you did help me so "Answer Accepted"